# Postgres import database from file syntax error

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I'm trying to import postgres database from dump file using command:

```
psql -d plus_se -f se.sql -v
```

I'm getting error:

> ```
> psql:se.sql:22: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""
> LINE 1: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DATABASECHANGELOG;
> ```

The dump was made using pg_dump and last time (on previous Ubuntu, I've recently installed fresh env) I was able to recreate database using this file.

Can anyone have a clue what might be wrong?

Comment: Those obnoxious backticks are invalid in Postgres (and standard SQL). That dump clearly wasn't taken with `pg_dump`

Comment: To @a_horse_with_no_name point. That looks like maybe you dumped from `mysql` and are trying to import into `postgres`. Those are two very different products so this isn't going to work.

Comment: You're right guys. Sorry for bothering you. My bad.